# Passing Transcribe variables to Freeform placeholder

Tags: solspace-freeform, stash, transcribe

I'm trying to pass a set a language variables into a respective set of Freeform generated inputs.

The obvious way to do it would be:

```
<div>
    <label for="freeform_first_name">{exp:transcribe:replace name='contact_name'}</label>
    {freeform:field:first_name attr:class="textinput" attr:placeholder="{exp:transcribe:replace name='contact_name'}"}
</div>
<div>
    <label for="freeform_email">{exp:transcribe:replace name='contact_email'}</label>
    {freeform:field:email attr:class="textinput" attr:placeholder="{exp:transcribe:replace name='contact_email'}"}
</div>
<div>
    <label for="freeform_user_message">{exp:transcribe:replace name='contact_message'}</label>
    {freeform:field:user_message attr:class="textarea" attr:placeholder="{exp:transcribe:replace name='contact_message'}"}
</div>
```

This results in the Label displaying the correct language variable as set by Transcribe. However the same language variables don't get parsed in the  Freeform's attribute placeholder.

I've tried to `stash:embed` the contact form and pass the variables from the originating template.

```
{stash:embed 
    name="snippets:contact-form" 
    process="end" 
    parse_depth="1" 
    stash:cntct_name="{exp:transcribe:replace name='contact_name'}" 
    stash:cntct_email="{exp:transcribe:replace name='contact_email'}" 
    stash:cntct_msg="{exp:transcribe:replace name='contact_message'}"}
```

And in the embed:

```
<div>
    <label for="freeform_first_name">{stash:cntct_name}</label>
    {freeform:field:first_name attr:class="textinput" attr:placeholder="{stash:cntct_name}"}
</div>
<div>
    <label for="freeform_email">{stash:cntct_email}</label>
    {freeform:field:email attr:class="textinput" attr:placeholder="{stash:cntct_email}"}
</div>
<div>
    <label for="freeform_user_message">{stash:cntct_msg}</label>
    {freeform:field:user_message attr:class="textarea" attr:placeholder="{stash:cntct_msg}"}
</div>
```

And still the FreeForm labels display the correct language variables. But the placeholder attributes are not getting generated, at all. Static text, though, does work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

did you try a parse="inward"?

```
{freeform:field:first_name attr:class="textinput" attr:placeholder="{exp:transcribe:replace name='contact_name' parse="inward"}"}
```